# GLM Get direction from rotation?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm making my camera class and it is almost done but now, i've found a problem. I need to convert a xyz rotation to xyz direction.

Currently i'm trying to do this but is doesn't work:

```
m_direction = glm::rotateX(glm::vec3(0,0,0), m_rotation.x);
m_direction = glm::rotateY(m_direction, m_rotation.y);
m_direction = glm::rotateZ(m_direction, m_rotation.z);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any rotation applied to the (0,0,0) vector will return this vector again. Think about which direction you want to have your camera looking when no rotations are applied. In a lot of applications, this will be the the negative z-axis, thus the initial vector should be (0,0,-1).

*Edit:* Assuming that the original direction is going along one of the major axes, the whole calculation can be simplified, since this corresponds to reading the corresponding column of the matrix. (thx to @datenwolf)

Comment: Furthermore, this is essentially extracting one/the column vectors from the matrix, so instead of multiplying a vector with the matrix you can just look at the matrix columns itself.